# Prompting with do while loop, can't seem to go in the loop

Tags: java

I am struggling getting "do/while loop" part of code to work. I HAVE TO use it as it is part of assignment. My goal is to direct user back to input upon invalid input. The valid input format for the date is mm/dd/yyyy. So if the user enters 2292014 I want to show him the error message and prompt him to reenter the date.

I'm super new to coding in java, but I know I'm not too far from the right solution to this problem.. Please, help if you can!

```
String date; //user entered date
int slash1; //position of the first slash
int slash2; //position of the second slash
boolean isValid; // true if date is valid
String day; // day part of the input date becomes a separate string
String month; // month part of the input date becomes a separate string
String year; // year part of the input date becomes a separate string
isValid = true; //initializing to true
do
{
  System.out.print("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy on or after 1860, such as 3/10/2015): ");
  date = stdIn.next(); //storing the input date
  slash1 = date.indexOf('/'); //position of the first slash in the user string
  slash2 = date.indexOf('/', slash1+1); //it looks for the position of the second string after the first one
  if (slash1 >= 0 && slash2 >= 0 && slash2 > (slash1+1))
  {
    month = date.substring(0, slash1);
    day = date.substring(slash1+1, slash2);
    year = date.substring(slash2+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < month.length(); i++)
    {
      if (!(Character.isDigit(month.charAt(i))))
      isValid = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < day.length(); i++)
    {
      if (!(Character.isDigit(day.charAt(i))))
      isValid = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < year.length(); i++)
    {
      if (!(Character.isDigit(year.charAt(i))))
      isValid = false;
    }
  } System.out.println("Invalid date: " + date + ". Please re-enter.");
} while (isValid == false);
```

Comment: Hint: `mm/dd/yyy` and `3/10/2015` contradict. According to your format the latter should be `03/10/2015`.

Comment: Yea, i know, but at this part of the assignment this kind of format (3/10/2015) is OK to be entered and should generate valid message, as long as it has two slashes and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition for the while loop is

```
isValid=false
```

I think you mean

```
isValid==false
```

Comment: thanks for catching that! But it still isn't going back in the loop.. any ideas what else could it be?

Comment: The only other reason I can think of is because none of the conditions of the if-statements inside the for-loops are ever met. Therefore isValid is never set to false

Comment: I would maybe suggest debugging by seeing if this works:

 if ((!(Character.isDigit(day.charAt(i))))==true)
      ---or try this and see if it continues the loop----      
 if ((!(Character.isDigit(day.charAt(i))))==false)

Answer (score 0):

I think at least one of your problems, unrelated to the do{}while() loop is that you never set your isValid variable to true in the loop. It starts out as true, but then if you enter an invalid date, the program will ask questions again, but it will not go back to the assumption that it is true. CyanogenCX was also correct in that you need the double equals sign to test for equality, instead of the single one for assignment. Try changing the line that says:

```
isValid=true;
```

from right before the "do" in the do while loop to the line after it.

Comment: I did try to move that line of code to the line after the "do", but it still is not looping.

Comment: You need it there even if you have more bugs; try updating your code on the question with it included, otherwise someone else is going to see the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug your code with a breakpoint set at: `if (slash1 >= 0 && slash2 >= 0 && slash2 > (slash1+1))`? And single-step through it (with [F6] in Eclipse, for instance)?

`isValid` never becomes `false`, regardless of whether you enter a valid or an invalid date as long as it contains numbers: `1/1/1` or `99/99/99.`

`isValid` becomes `false` only if you enter a letter: `a/1/1`.

Furhermore, the error message is shown every time, since it doesn't depend on `isValid`.

And there are a few more things with room for improvement. May I suggest to take a tour to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I am not sure how to either debug or single step through it with F6..
I had the code working to give me false and true messages for corresponding format entered - False for 03//2016 and 03162015 and 03/2016 and True for 200/2/2014 which is what was required of me at this stage - to verify at least 2 slashes, no empty strings, and for date to contain only digits. The only thing that I needed to change at next stage was to ask user to reenter the date if it was False based on conditions that worked on the previous stage. And I can't seem to get it to work.